# Collections Replacement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, collections

Do we have collections in SQL server ? like Oracle collections (TYPE)

For Eg:

```
create or replace TYPE OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_REC AS OBJECT (NUMBER_1 number(10),VARCHAR_1 varchar2(30));

create or replace type OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_TBL AS TABLE OF OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_REC;

Cursor C2 is select OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_REC(O_ID, O_NAME) from Organization;

Open C2;
Fetch C2 BULK COLLECT into L_OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_TBL;
Close C2;


for i in 1..L_OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_TBL.count loop
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(L_OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_TBL(i).NUMBER_1||'  ');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_OBJ_NUM_VARCHAR_TBL(i).VARCHAR_1);
end loop;
```

This is the sample code, how do we need to write in sql server ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the TABLE type parameters.  You can pass in a list of rows with that.

Works something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE
(
    MyID INT NOT NULL
)
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    @MyParam MyTableType
AS
BEGIN 
    ...
END
```

Comment: But how can I access values in that TABLE type ? Do I need to write again select statements only ? @PhillipXT

Comment: You use that parameter as you would any other table.  Eg. `SELECT MyID FROM @MyParam`

Comment: Can I write select * from SomeTable into @MyParam; and can I access the column in that type by using MyParam.MyID ??? @PhillipXT

Comment: You can use it like a table, so you could do `INSERT INTO @MyTable ( Field1, Field2 ) SELECT x1, x2 FROM OtherTable` and then `SELECT Field1 FROM @MyTable`.